# How to segregate data into two dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a link with json data from which I want to segregate data into two dataframe.

My Code as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 10000)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

for x in range(len(data['records']['data'])):
    print(data['records']['data'][x])
```

The Output contains rows like below where "CE" & "PE" data is available:

```
{'strikePrice': 13900, 'expiryDate': '23-Apr-2020', 'PE': {'strikePrice': 13900, 'expiryDate': '23-Apr-2020', 'underlying': 'BANKNIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXBANKNIFTY23-04-2020PE13900.00', 'openInterest': 1597, 'changeinOpenInterest': 1589, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 19862.5, 'totalTradedVolume': 9101, 'impliedVolatility': 110.76, 'lastPrice': 1.65, 'change': -1.5, 'pChange': -47.61904761904762, 'totalBuyQuantity': 49800, 'totalSellQuantity': 17560, 'bidQty': 40, 'bidprice': 1.75, 'askQty': 460, 'askPrice': 2.35, 'underlyingValue': 20681.45}, 'CE': {'strikePrice': 13900, 'expiryDate': '23-Apr-2020', 'underlying': 'BANKNIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXBANKNIFTY23-04-2020CE13900.00', 'openInterest': 0, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 2, 'impliedVolatility': 162.07, 'lastPrice': 6901.1, 'change': 3502.4000000000005, 'pChange': 103.05116662253218, 'totalBuyQuantity': 2620, 'totalSellQuantity': 2620, 'bidQty': 200, 'bidprice': 6629.85, 'askQty': 200, 'askPrice': 7208.75, 'underlyingValue': 20681.45}}

{'strikePrice': 13900, 'expiryDate': '30-Apr-2020', 'PE': {'strikePrice': 13900, 'expiryDate': '30-Apr-2020', 'underlying': 'BANKNIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXBANKNIFTY30-04-2020PE13900.00', 'openInterest': 989, 'changeinOpenInterest': 12, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 1.2282497441146367, 'totalTradedVolume': 134, 'impliedVolatility': 98.26, 'lastPrice': 16.3, 'change': -4.899999999999999, 'pChange': -23.113207547169807, 'totalBuyQuantity': 32900, 'totalSellQuantity': 4100, 'bidQty': 20, 'bidprice': 16.3, 'askQty': 20, 'askPrice': 17, 'underlyingValue': 20681.45}, 'CE': {'strikePrice': 13900, 'expiryDate': '30-Apr-2020', 'underlying': 'BANKNIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXBANKNIFTY30-04-2020CE13900.00', 'openInterest': 1, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 5000, 'change': -5000, 'pChange': -100, 'totalBuyQuantity': 2640, 'totalSellQuantity': 2840, 'bidQty': 20, 'bidprice': 6242.05, 'askQty': 20, 'askPrice': 7401.65, 'underlyingValue': 20681.45}}

{'strikePrice': 13900, 'expiryDate': '14-May-2020', 'PE': {'strikePrice': 13900, 'expiryDate': '14-May-2020', 'underlying': 'BANKNIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXBANKNIFTY14-05-2020PE13900.00', 'openInterest': 0, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 0, 'change': 0, 'pChange': -100, 'totalBuyQuantity': 100, 'totalSellQuantity': 0, 'bidQty': 100, 'bidprice': 0.3, 'askQty': 0, 'askPrice': 0, 'underlyingValue': 20681.45}, 'CE': {'strikePrice': 13900, 'expiryDate': '14-May-2020', 'underlying': 'BANKNIFTY', 'identifier': 'OPTIDXBANKNIFTY14-05-2020CE13900.00', 'openInterest': 0, 'changeinOpenInterest': 0, 'pchangeinOpenInterest': 0, 'totalTradedVolume': 0, 'impliedVolatility': 0, 'lastPrice': 0, 'change': 0, 'pChange': -100, 'totalBuyQuantity': 2420, 'totalSellQuantity': 2420, 'bidQty': 2420, 'bidprice': 6223.45, 'askQty': 2420, 'askPrice': 7565.05, 'underlyingValue': 20681.45}}
```

I want to store the CE & PE values in two separate dataframe with column name as

```
['strikePrice','expiryDate', 'underlying', 'identifier', 'openInterest', 'changeinOpenInterest', 'pchangeinOpenInterest', 'totalTradedVolume','impliedVolatility', 'lastPrice', 'change', 'pChange', 'totalBuyQuantity', 'totalSellQuantity', 'bidQty', 'bidprice', 'askQty', 'askPrice', 'underlyingValue']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a bit of [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with some friends from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) should help in getting the data into separate dataframes:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'
}
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

#list comprehension here
#note that it is nested, since the data we are truly keen on
#is embedded in a list
#this will give us a tuple of the key, and the dataframe of the values
#as the values are dictionaries
res = [[(key, pd.DataFrame.from_dict(value, orient='index').T)
        for key, value in entry.items()
        if key in ['PE', 'CE']]
       for entry in data['records']['data']]

from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain
d = defaultdict(list)

#group the values into a pair
#they will be a combined list of dataframes
#belonging to either PE or CE    
for k, v in chain.from_iterable(res):
    d[k].append(v)

#now we can merge the values
#and keep our result as a dictionary
#this allows us to access PE or CE via keys   
result = {key: pd.concat(values) for key, values in d.items()}

#now, we can access either PE or CE
#dataframe is quite long, so this is a small part of it
result['PE'].iloc[:3,:5]


 strikePrice    expiryDate  underlying  identifier                openInterest
0   13900      23-Apr-2020  BANKNIFTY   OPTIDXBANKNIFTY23-04-2020PE13900.00 1597
0   13900      30-Apr-2020  BANKNIFTY   OPTIDXBANKNIFTY30-04-2020PE13900.00 989
0   13900      14-May-2020  BANKNIFTY   OPTIDXBANKNIFTY14-05-2020PE13900.00 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that shows one way to accomplish what you are looking for:

```
# initialize dataframes to hold data
pe_df = pd.DataFrame()
ce_df = pd.DataFrame()

# loop through records
for x in range(len(data['records']['data'])):

    # extract the record
    record = data['records']['data'][x]
    # print the record
    print(record)

    # extract the 'PE' and 'CE' data
    pe_row = record['PE']
    ce_row = record['CE']

    # append the row to the appropriate dataframe
    pe_df = pe_df.append(pd.Series(pe_row), ignore_index=True)
    ce_df = ce_df.append(pd.Series(ce_row), ignore_index=True)
```

I have assumed that the record data is in the form that you've shown in your question.

Comment: Sir, I have edited my question to bring more clarity to my question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `json_obj` is the output you've pasted above,
The transformation can be done simply using -

**PE**

```
pe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_obj['PE'], orient='index').reset_index()
pe.columns = ['param', 'value'] # Optional renaming of columns
print(pe)

"""
                    param                                value
0             strikePrice                                13900
1              expiryDate                          23-Apr-2020
2              underlying                            BANKNIFTY
3              identifier  OPTIDXBANKNIFTY23-04-2020PE13900.00
4            openInterest                                 1597
5    changeinOpenInterest                                 1589
6   pchangeinOpenInterest                              19862.5
7       totalTradedVolume                                 9101
8       impliedVolatility                               110.76
9               lastPrice                                 1.65
10                 change                                 -1.5
11                pChange                              -47.619
12       totalBuyQuantity                                49800
13      totalSellQuantity                                17560
14                 bidQty                                   40
15               bidprice                                 1.75
16                 askQty                                  460
17               askPrice                                 2.35
18        underlyingValue                              20681.5
"""
```

Similarly, repeat the above steps for transforming `CE` into a data-frame.

Comment: Sir, I have edited my question to bring more clarity to my question

Comment: Sir, I want all param here as column name and values under indivisual columns

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem as below. Is there any other efficient way to get the desired result?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 10000)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=BANKNIFTY"
records = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

df_PE = pd.DataFrame()
df_CE = pd.DataFrame()
# print(len(records['records']['data']))
for x in range(len(records['records']['data'])):
    if records['records']['data'][x]['expiryDate'] == "23-Apr-2020":
        try:
            PE = pd.DataFrame([records['records']['data'][x]['PE']])
            df_PE = df_PE.append(PE)
        except Exception as err:
            pass

        try:
            CE = pd.DataFrame([records['records']['data'][x]['CE']])
            df_CE = df_CE.append(CE)
        except Exception as err:
            pass

print(df_PE)
print(df_CE)
```